# how can I improve blob detection with python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, tracking

So I have this flapping winged robot, where I drew some circles on the wing that I thought would be easy to track. As the wing moves in each frame, some circles may appear blurrier or elliptic compared to other frames.
My goal is to generate a dictionary with keys that represent a circle's unique ID, and a value that is a list of (x,y) coordinates for each frame. So for `k` circles and `n` frames:

```
result = {
 1: [(x11,y11),(x12,y12),...,(x1n,y1n)],
 2: [(x21,y21),(x22,y22),...,(x2n,y2n)],
 ...,
 k: [(xk1,yk1),(xk2,yk2),...,(xkn,ykn)]
}
```

currently, I use `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create`, which does find *some* of the circles in each frame, and I match between two consecutive circles by measuring the Euclidian distance w.r.t every circle in the previous frame.
Of course, as not all circles are always found, I get these holes in the data that I want to fill in.

**How can I fill in these gaps?**

While I don't think that the code adds much value, I've added it here as well:

```
def blob_trajectory(camera_dirname: str,
                    crop_params_filename='crop_params.pkl',
                    first_image_name='Img000001.jpg',
                    photos_sub_dirname='photos',
                    cropped_dirname='cropped',
                    **kwargs):
    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.minThreshold = kwargs["min_thres"]
    params.maxThreshold = kwargs["max_thres"]
    params.filterByCircularity = 1
    params.minCircularity = kwargs["min_circ"]
    params.maxCircularity = kwargs["max_circ"]
    params.filterByConvexity = 1
    params.minInertiaRatio = kwargs["min_conv"]
    params.maxInertiaRatio = kwargs["max_conv"]
    params.filterByArea = 1
    params.minArea = kwargs["min_area"]  # number of pixels
    params.maxArea = kwargs["max_area"]
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
    images_path = os.path.join(camera_dirname, photos_sub_dirname)
    cropped_path = os.path.join(camera_dirname, cropped_dirname)
    frame0 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(cropped_path, 'frame_0000.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    prev_blobs = detector.detect(frame0)
    blob_trajectories = {}
    for image_name in os.listdir(images_path)[1:]:
        frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(cropped_path, image_name), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        curr_blobs = detector.detect(frame)
        for i, kp in enumerate(prev_blobs):
            kp.class_id = i
        distances = np.zeros((len(prev_blobs), len(curr_blobs)))
        for i, kp1 in enumerate(prev_blobs):
            for j, kp2 in enumerate(curr_blobs):
                distances[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(np.array(kp1.pt) - np.array(kp2.pt))
        row_ind, col_ind = scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment(distances)
        for i, j in zip(row_ind, col_ind):
            if distances[i, j] < 10:
                curr_blobs[i].class_id = prev_blobs[j].class_id
        for kp in prev_blobs:
            blob_id = kp.class_id
            if blob_id not in blob_trajectories:
                blob_trajectories[blob_id] = []
            blob_trajectories[blob_id].append(kp.pt)
        im_with_blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, curr_blobs, np.array([]), (255, 0, 0),
                                          cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
        plt.imshow(im_with_blobs)
        plt.show()
        prev_blobs = curr_blobs
    return blob_trajectories
```

Comment: bad targets. get retroreflective foil, stick some pieces there, then use a ring light around your camera. that'll make them pop out of any picture. dial the exposure down so everything that isn't retroreflective and illuminated by the ring light will look dark.

Comment: Cool, haven't really thought of a non-code approach. In that case, why ring light? wouldn't a good old projector do a better job? @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: light has to come from very close to the camera. anything else will not work. *retroreflective*. it's the stuff on road signs so they light up at night from your headlights.

Comment: I'm only asking because the footage is from a high speed camera, and I'm concerned that some light sources might flicker in high frame rate. any suggestion on that?

Comment: get a light source that is synchronized to your camera's frame rate (triggered by the camera's start of exposure). or get light that flickers fast enough, or is at least set to a multiple of the frame rate. or get light that doesn't flicker at all. flickering can only happen if there is any dimming at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try it while referring to the code below.

Moved the initialization of blob_trajectories outside the loop to ensure the dictionary is not reset in each iteration.

These modifications should help you generate a dictionary with keys representing the circle's unique ID and values as lists of (x, y) coordinates for each frame. The code will track the circles across frames by matching them based on Euclidean distance. It will also handle missing or newly detected circles and update the trajectories accordingly.

Remember to adjust the blob detection parameters (kwargs) based on your specific requirements and experiment with different parameter values to optimize the results.

```
def blob_trajectory(camera_dirname: str,
                    crop_params_filename='crop_params.pkl',
                    first_image_name='Img000001.jpg',
                    photos_sub_dirname='photos',
                    cropped_dirname='cropped',
                    **kwargs):
    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.minThreshold = kwargs["min_thres"]
    params.maxThreshold = kwargs["max_thres"]
    params.filterByCircularity = 1
    params.minCircularity = kwargs["min_circ"]
    params.maxCircularity = kwargs["max_circ"]
    params.filterByConvexity = 1
    params.minInertiaRatio = kwargs["min_conv"]
    params.maxInertiaRatio = kwargs["max_conv"]
    params.filterByArea = 1
    params.minArea = kwargs["min_area"]  # number of pixels
    params.maxArea = kwargs["max_area"]
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
    images_path = os.path.join(camera_dirname, photos_sub_dirname)
    cropped_path = os.path.join(camera_dirname, cropped_dirname)

    # Initialize the dictionary to store blob trajectories
    blob_trajectories = {}

    # Read the first frame and detect blobs
    frame0 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(cropped_path, first_image_name), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    prev_blobs = detector.detect(frame0)
    for i, kp in enumerate(prev_blobs):
        kp.class_id = i

    # Add initial blobs to trajectories
    for kp in prev_blobs:
        blob_id = kp.class_id
        if blob_id not in blob_trajectories:
            blob_trajectories[blob_id] = []
        blob_trajectories[blob_id].append(kp.pt)

    # Process subsequent frames
    for image_name in os.listdir(images_path)[1:]:
        frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(cropped_path, image_name), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        curr_blobs = detector.detect(frame)

        # Compute distances between blobs in previous and current frames
        distances = np.zeros((len(prev_blobs), len(curr_blobs)))
        for i, kp1 in enumerate(prev_blobs):
            for j, kp2 in enumerate(curr_blobs):
                distances[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(np.array(kp1.pt) - np.array(kp2.pt))

        # Perform matching using Hungarian algorithm (linear_sum_assignment)
        row_ind, col_ind = scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment(distances)

        # Update blob IDs based on matching results
        for i, j in zip(row_ind, col_ind):
            if distances[i, j] < 10:
                curr_blobs[j].class_id = prev_blobs[i].class_id

        # Add new blobs to trajectories
        for kp in curr_blobs:
            blob_id = kp.class_id
            if blob_id not in blob_trajectories:
                blob_trajectories[blob_id] = []
            blob_trajectories[blob_id].append(kp.pt)

        # Visualize blobs on the current frame
        im_with_blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, curr_blobs, np.array([]), (255, 0, 0),
                                          cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
        plt.imshow(im_with_blobs)
        plt.show()

        # Update previous blobs for the next iteration
        prev_blobs = curr_blobs

    return blob_trajectories
```